# Multiple tenants in Sharepoint Online- PRO and DEV

Tags: sharepoint-online, multi-tenancy

We have one tenant for the company in Sharepoint Online, and we're working in integrating new services.
We have got the following piece of advice: 
Why not use a DEV tenant to make your changes, and test and avoid problems.

As far as i know, it shoud be:

company.sharepoint.com

company-dev.sharepoint.com

Ok, it seems a good idea, but we aren't sure how to acomplish it.
How can i get this scenario? 
It would great to have the same accounts in both tenants, but i'm not so sure that it could be possible.

What would be best practices for this scenario?

Comment: It really depends on your requirements, we have test and live tenancy and we use test tenant for first release any development work.  There is no replication between these two tenants.  You can sync users to both tenants but why would you want to do this? There are licence issues around.

Comment: Umm maybe your approach could feet our requirements.
Could you elaborate a bit more about get this dev/tes tenant environment?
Could you manage both from the same account/console?

Comment: You will need to elaborate bit more about your what you are exactly trying to achieve and more importantly why you want to have separate environment.  Test and Live tenant both are completely separate and data / users are not shared unless you do install AAD Connect to sync your users from on premises server on both the tenants.

Comment: The idea is to have a dev environment isolated from production to be able to test new packages and make test in this environment.
It would be ideal to have the same users and data in both environments, but, if that suppose more licensing i think is not the way to go for us.
Having separate data allows to test, so it could be enough.
The main question would be how do we setup this tenant company-dev.sharepoint.com and what are the best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pay for the separate tenant, but you can try and create a developer tenancy which will be free for a year:

https://dev.office.com/devprogram

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment

You will need to use AAD Connect to integrate on-premises users. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect

Comment: OK, thanks for the information and links.
But i have some questions:
- how could we handle two tenants? Could they be in the same suscription? 
- The new tenant's users come from AD integration or how could be populate them?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Both the tenants will be completely separate.