# Multiple tenants in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, multi-tenancy

My company have a contract on his Azure Tenant (and need to keep it that way). So I required a new sharepoint for test inside the same tenant.
6 years ago, it look impossible ([Multiple tenants in Sharepoint Online- PRO and DEV](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213662/multiple-tenants-in-sharepoint-online-pro-and-dev)

The premiss was great, having those 2 sharepoint online instance for 1 azure Tenant.

- company.sharepoint.com
- company-dev.sharepoint.com

both of those will be linked to company.azure.com/company.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: As per my knowledge, it is still currently impossible...

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate Azure tenant. This is primarily because SharePoint Online relies on the Azure tenant's Azure AD instance for identity management. Two SharePoint Online tenants cannot share the same Azure AD instance.